# Circumstances under which squared differentials can be neglected

Tags: calculus, differential

With the help of the image, we can derive the formula for the differential area under the red curve, which is $y = f(x)$.

[image]

The area is given by the sum of the area of the rectangular region, which is exact, and the triangular region, which is approximate.  Like so:

$dA=ydx+\frac{1}{2}dxdy$

Now since $dy=f'dx$ this can be written as:

$dA=ydx+\frac{1}{2}dxf'dx = ydx+\frac{1}{2}f'dx^2$

Since the last term is much smaller than the first, we can neglect it to find the area as:

$dA=ydx$

Ok, familiar result.  However, my question is:

Isn't it true that the neglected term is much smaller than the other term only when $y\gg\frac{1}{2}f'dx$?  How can we know that this is always the case? Could it be possible that there is a huge, near vertical slope in the vicinity of y that makes these terms comparable? How can we rule that out without knowing the details of the curve?

Thanks

Comment: $y\gg\frac12f'\,\mathrm dx$ because $y$ is finite while $\mathrm dx$ is infinitesimal.

Comment: Right, but again what if $f'$ is nearly vertical?  Then we have a near infinite times a near zero.  How do we know this is always less much much less than y?

Comment: $\mathrm dx$ being infinitesimal means that you can make it as small as you like. For any chosen $x$, no matter how large $y$ and $f'$ are, they are both finite. So you can make $\mathrm dx$ small enough that the right side is negligible compared to the left.